# How can I prevent click event from parent DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

say, I have

```
HTML:
<div onclick="parent()">
    <div onclick="child()"></div>
</div>

SCRIPT: {
function parent() {
    console.log("I'm your father");
}

function child() {
    console.log("You're not my father");
}
```

In this situation, if I click child element, it's parent element is clicked also, so parent() child() both are called. How can I call child() only without it's parent being clicked?

Comment: `Event.stopPropagation()` (also, better to assign handlers in Javascript rather than HTML attributes - that's as bad as `eval`)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Do you mean I cannot use onclick, ng-click... for binding function do DOM? Should I use bunch of JQueries?

Comment: it could be right for performance-wise but, isn't that easy to maintain rather than bunch of jquery selectors?

Comment: @kispi No where did you mention `ng-click` in your question, but inline `onclick` is bad.

Comment: @kispi `ng-click` is different from the `onclick` attribute. The problem isn't performance - the problem is code readability and maintainability.  Inline event handlers are essentially `eval` inside HTML markup - they're bad practice and result in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Attach the handlers with Javascript instead. (no, there's absolutely no need for jQuery just to assign a handler) Separate presentation from content: keep content in your HTML and your Javascript in your Javascript.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks, but how about ng-click? Can we think it seperates presentation and content? Or is it not a problem since it's 'ng' and everyone knows that there will be everything inside of component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function parent() {
    console.log("I'm your father");
}

function child() {
    console.log("You're not my father");
    window.event.cancelBubble = "true";
}
```

```html
<div onclick="parent()" style="height : 40px;width:40px; background:blue">
    <div onclick="child()" style="height : 10px;width:10px; background:red"></div>
</div>
```

You can use

```
window.event.cancelBubble = "true"
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. didn't know about cancleBubble

Comment: @kispi The `Event.cancelBubble` property is a historical alias to `Event.stopPropagation()`, use the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in your child click event to stop event bubbling.

```
 event.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) from `child()` which will prevent further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

```js
function parent() {
    console.log("I'm your father");
}

function child(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("You're not my father");
}
```

```html
<div onclick="parent()">Parent
    <div onclick="child(event)">Child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Parent click doesn't seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

That's called `bubbling`. The process is called “bubbling”, because events `bubble` from the inner element up through parents like a bubble in the water.

When an event happens on an element, it first runs the handlers on it, then on its parent, then all the way up on other ancestors.

You can use `stopPropagation` method.

```js
function parent() {
    console.log("I'm your father");
}

function child(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("You're not my father");
}
```

```css
#parent{
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

#child {
  background-color:blue; 
  width:30px;
  align:center;
  height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" onclick="parent()">
    <div id="child" onclick="child(event)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: for those bounty hunters, yeah